# Does login history log from terminal show whether it's from TouchID or typed pwd?

Tags: terminal

I have read every post on this topic and still can't find an answer. Please do not flag this as a duplicate post, whoever moderates this forum.

Do the logs identify whether the login was performed with TouchID versus manual password entry? If not, is there somewhere to see that metadata? Hoping it's in the log file and if not, if it's neatly tracked anywhere.

Comment: Don't ask the same question as you have already asked. That is obviously a duplicate. If you don't think your original question was a duplicate then **EDIT** that question to show why it is not a duplicate (in this case one way would be to show that last does not work) ALso show what research you have done.

Comment: Have you tried logging in with both methods then inspecting the logs?